# Save and retrieve a date in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing an app at the moment, where I store a date and calculate the amount between that and X .

Functionally it works, but I need to store the date and retrieving it.

Later on it should be more than one day stored where I can calc the period

Its my first time on writing in Kotlin and doing android development so I am kind of confused how I should store the date and how I can retrieve that date .

I would be happy for retrieving help
Sincerly Toscan

Comment: welcome to SO. what have you tried doing so far ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: I tried shared Preferences which stored but couldn't retrieve data correctly and I also treid firebase